# grafana dashboard for prometheus not working

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am newbie to grafana and prometheus. I setup prometheus, grafana, alertmanager, nodeexporter and cadvisor using the docker-compose.yml from this post https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus

And imported grafana dashboard #893 from https://grafana.com/dashboards/893

But the dashboard is not working as I can see N/A in some panels. For example below are the queries used by the panels and I couldn't figure out how to get the values for the template variable in the query. I looked at http://node-exporter:9100/metrics and do not see a value for variable '$server'

```
Query1: time() - node_boot_time{instance=~"$server:.*"}
Query2:min((node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"xfs|ext4",instance=~"$server:.*"} - node_filesystem_free_bytes{fstype=~"xfs|ext4",instance=~"$server:.*"} )/ node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"xfs|ext4",instance=~"$server:.*"})
```

What should I configure for node-exporter and prometheus to evaluate the template variable $server in the queries?

Comment: Also in my dashboard settings --> variables i see a variable 'server' of type 'query' and query=label_values(node_boot_time, instance). How does this query work

Answer (score 1):

`$server` is a Grafana [template variable](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/). These usually show up as dropdowns at the top of the Grafana dashboard.

`label_values` is a [Prometheus-specific Grafana function](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable) that is applied to a Prometheus query. Your particular example, `label_values(node_boot_time, instance)` will return all values of the `instance` label for all `node_boot_time` metrics collected by Prometheus (i.e. all node exporter targets monitored by Prometheus).

I have no experience with the particular dashboard you are using (or node exporter, for that matter), but usually the cause for some panels displaying "N/A" or no values while other panels work just fine is that the underlying metric names might have changed. You can click on the header of the problematic panel in Grafana, select *Edit*, then click on the *Metrics* tab to try different metric names. For "inspiration", check the `/metrics` endpoint of your node exporter. If you don't know how to get to it, on the Prometheus web interface navigate to *Status* > *Targets* and click on the URL of your node exporter.

Comment: I did change the metric name from node_boot_time to node_boot_time_seconds as I can see this in node-exporter/metrics. but for some reason it looks like grfana couldn't evaluate the query. I can see values for instance when type in 'node_boot_time' to prometheus query. I will research further

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but it still didn't work for me. 
The reason is that the label_values(...) works fine obtaining all the instance names that have a node_boot_time metric.

The problem is in the regex that follows the expression (next line). In my case it was something tricky resembling "/([^:].*):/". My instance names start with "i-" and contain no colon, so nothing was being selected. I just used a ProductCode to figure out the right instances instead.